# Removing last line and white spaces while writing arrays to file

Tags: java, file

Writing data in a file with loop line by line will cause the last line to be 'newline'. Consider this:

```
try {
  outFile = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outFileName));
  for (int i = 0; i < some_condition; i++) {
    for (String record: aLine) {
       outFile.write(record + " ");
    }
    outFile.write("\n");
  }
} catch(IOException e) {
  System.out.println("found error!");
}
```

Also the last item in each row is " ". What is the efficient way to trim such white spaces and newline?

I can divide the loop to 0...n-2 and n-1 but is not very good for big codes. I am looking for some file based solutions like this:

```
try {
  outFile = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outFileName));
  for (int i = 0; i < some_condition; i++) {
    for (String record: aLine) {
       outFile.write(record + " ");
    }
    outFile.REMOVE_LAST_CHARACTER;  // trim " "
    outFile.write("\n");
  }
} catch(IOException e) {
  System.out.println("found error!");
}
outFile.REMOVE_LAST_LINE;
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append it to `StringBuilder` and then at last remove the last `character` by trimming the `String` or you can manually check in `for` loop while appending `" "`. For `\n` newline character, You can append every line to a main `StringBuilder` which keeps track of whole `file` and trim the `extra space` at last.

```
StringBuilder all_lines = new StringBuilder(); //To store every line

for (int i = 0; i < some_condition; i++) {
    StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();
    for (String record: aLine) {
        line.append(record).append(" ");       //To store every words
    }
    all_lines.append(line.toString().trim());
    all_lines.append("\n");
}

outFile.write(all_lines.toString().trim());
outFile.close();
```

Comment: That is good. But it doesn't remove the last new line. Is that correct?

Comment: I edited the post. It is actually nested loop. So the last line is always "\n" which I want to remove

Answer (score 1):

You can write the space and new line before the record, here is an example:

```
try {
  outFile = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outFileName));
  for (int i = 0; i < some_condition; i++) {
    if(i!=0){
       outFile.write("\n");
    }

    boolean firstRecord = true;
    for (String record: aLine) {
       outFile.write((firstRecord ? "" : " ") + record);
       firstRecord = false;
    }
  }
} catch(IOException e) {
  System.out.println("found error!");
}
```